# Why is an old view model responding to a notification?

Tags: swift, mvvm, notifications

I’m creating a weightlifting calculator application (Swift 4) using MVVM and have been trying for 2 days to figure out why a view model that should have died is still responding to a `UserDefaults.defaultsDidChange` event notification.

[image]

1. I launch the app:

   - At launch, in the AppDelegate, I create a new lift event object and use it to initialize a new `CalculatorLiftEventViewModelFromLiftEvent` for the `CalculatorViewController':
2. I calculate a lift and save it
3. I tap the + button to create a new lift:

   - this causes a new, empty lift event object to be created
   - this new lift event object is used to initialize a new `CalculatorLiftEventViewModelFromLiftEvent` object
   - this new `CalculatorLiftEventViewModelFromLiftEvent` is then assigned to the `CalculatorViewController`'s viewModel property, replacing the one created when the app launched
   - the values on the calculator screen are zeroed out, ready for a new lift event to be entered
4. I tap the Settings button to go to Settings where I change the Formula associated with the current lift event.
5. The new Formula is saved as the default and the `UserDefaults.defaultsDidChange` notification is fired
6. HERE’S THE PART I CAN’T FIGURE OUT: the original view model is still alive and it’s still listening for UserDefault notifications. When I close the Settings screen and go back to the Calculator view, the values from the prior lift event that had been cleared out now reappear.

Here’s what happens when the + (new) button on the Calculator screen is tapped:

```
@objc fileprivate func onNewButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let newLiftEvent = dataManager.createNewLiftEvent()
    viewModel = CalculatorLiftEventViewModelFromLiftEvent(withLiftEvent: newLiftEvent, dataManager: dataManager)

    setupView()
}
```

Here’s how the `CalculatorLiftEventViewModelFromLiftEvent` is initialized:

```
init(withLiftEvent liftEvent: LiftEventRepresentable, dataManager: CoreDataHelper) {
    self.modelLiftEvent = liftEvent
    self.liftName = Dynamic("\(modelLiftEvent.lift.liftName)")
    self.weightLiftedTextField = Dynamic(modelLiftEvent.liftWeight.value)
    self.repetitionsTextField = Dynamic("\(modelLiftEvent.repetitions)")
    self.oneRepMaxTextField = Dynamic(modelLiftEvent.oneRepMax.value)
    self.unitsTextField = Dynamic("\(UserDefaults.weightUnit())")
    self.weightPercentages = Dynamic( [ : ] )
    self.dataManager = dataManager

    super.init()

    subscribeToNotifications()
}
```

**UPDATE:** Here are the `deinit` and the `addObserver`s in `CalculatorLiftEventViewModelFromLiftEvent`. Notice I'm not using block-based observations.

```
deinit {
    print("I got to the deinit method")
    unsubscribeFromNotifications()
}

func subscribeToNotifications() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                                    selector: #selector(liftNameDidChangeNotification(_:)),
                                                    name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: LiftEventNotifications.LiftNameDidChangeNotification),
                                                    object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                                    selector: #selector(weightUnitDidChangeNotification(_:)),
                                                    name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: LiftEventNotifications.WeightUnitDidChangeNotification),
                                                    object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                                    selector: #selector(roundingOptionDidChangeNotification(_:)),
                                                    name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: UserDefaultsNotifications.roundingOptionDidChangeNotification),
                                                    object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.defaultsDidChange), name: UserDefaults.didChangeNotification,
                                                    object: nil)
    }
```

**--- END UPDATE**

I pass the modelLiftEvent when segueing to the `SettingsViewController`:

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let identifier = segue.identifier {
            switch identifier {
            case a:...
            case b:...
            case "SettingsSegue":
            if let nav = segue.destination as? UINavigationController {
                let destinationViewController = nav.topViewController as! SettingsViewController
                destinationViewController.dismissalDelegate = self

                let settingsViewModel = SettingsViewModelFromLiftEvent(withLiftEvent: self.viewModel.modelLiftEvent)
                destinationViewController.settingsViewModel = settingsViewModel
                destinationViewController.dataManager = dataManager
                settingsViewModel.dataManager = dataManager
            }
```

Finally, in `CalculatorLiftEventViewModelFromLiftEvent`, I’ve put a break point here because this is called when the view model hears the `UserDefaults.defaultsDidChange` notification. At this point, I have also verified that this `CalculatorLiftEventViewModelFromLiftEvent` is the old one, not the new one created when I tapped the + button:

```
@objc func defaultsDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    let oneRepMax = modelLiftEvent.calculateOneRepMax()

    guard oneRepMax.value != 0.0 else { return }

    let weightPercentages = getWeightPercentages(weight: oneRepMax.value)
    self.weightPercentages.value = weightPercentages

    weightLiftedTextField.value = modelLiftEvent.liftWeight.value
    repetitionsTextField.value = "\(modelLiftEvent.repetitions)"
    oneRepMaxTextField.value = modelLiftEvent.oneRepMax.value
}
```

I've read through a bunch of documentation about the life cycle of objects but haven't found anything that helps. I expect that when the new `CalculatorLiftEventViewModelFromLiftEvent` is created and assigned to the `CalculatorViewController''s viewModel property, it would replace the reference to the old one and it would cease to exist. Evidently, that's not what's happening.

Does anyone have any idea why when I go from the Calculator view (step 3) that has no values (except for 0.0) to the Settings and then come back, the prior lift event values are displayed?

Comment: Not enough code to be sure, but it looks like `CalculatorLiftEventViewModelFromLiftEvent` is registered as an observer for notifications (hinted at by the call to `subscribeToNotifications()`). If true, that would hold a reference to the object keeping it alive (and, according to your breakpoint evidence, continuing to send it notifications to act upon.)

Comment: Thanks, @pauln. I'm happy to add more code that you think could be relevant. I reviewed Apple's documentation about selector-based observation APIs they say the starting with iOS 9.0, you don't need to unregister an observer in its dealloc method. They go on to say, "Otherwise, you should call removeObserver(_:name:object:) before observer or any object passed to this method is deallocated." Not sure what 'otherwise' means. Otherwise what?

Comment: Funnily enough I was just reading about this today here https://oleb.net/blog/2018/01/notificationcenter-removeobserver/?utm_campaign=iOS%2BDev%2BWeekly&utm_medium=email&utm_source=iOS_Dev_Weekly_Issue_334.  Basically although one part of the documentation says no both the Foundation notes and the addObserver documentation say yes.  So for now you still need to do it and it doesn't hurt anyway.

Comment: By 'otherwise', they mean apps with targets prior to iOS 9.0 and macOS 10.11. Still, it's suspicious and trying an unregister could be revealing.

Also, are your view model types objects or structs?

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth - Ha! I read that this morning too. It's actually the reason I sounded like I knew what I was talking about. I'm going to try it and report back.

Comment: You aren't subscribed to iOS Dev Weekly by any chance because it was in the latest issue.

Comment: @pauln - they're objects. I wanted to keep them structs but I couldn't because, reasons. I'm sure that means I'm having them do something they shouldn't really be doing, but that'll be the next problem I tackle.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth, Yep, that's how I found it.

Comment: I added a `deinit` method as you can see in the update above. However, it's never being called. Because the notifications the class is subscribed to hold references to the object, wouldn't those need to be removed first? Then I would think the object would be deallocated and the `deinit` would be called.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the problem of the prior `liftEvent` being displayed after clearing the calculator, changing the default formula, and coming back to the calculator screen.

On `CalculatorViewController`, when the + button is tapped, instead of creating a new viewModel and assigning it to the viewModel property, I'm asking my AppDelegate to create both a new `CalculatorViewController` and `CalculatorLiftEventViewModelFromLiftEvent` by using the `launchCalculatorViewController` method which does this when the app launches.

The original code in `CalculatorViewController`:

```
@objc fileprivate func onNewButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let newLiftEvent = dataManager.createNewLiftEvent()
    viewModel = CalculatorLiftEventViewModelFromLiftEvent(withLiftEvent: newLiftEvent, dataManager: dataManager)

    self.percentagesTableView.reloadData()

    setupView()
}
```

Now the new code in `CalculatorViewController`:

```
@objc fileprivate func onNewButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.launchCalculatorViewController()

}
```

and in `AppDelegate`:

```
func launchCalculatorViewController() {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    if let initialViewController: CalculatorViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as? CalculatorViewController {

        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController

        let liftEvent = dataManager.createNewLiftEvent()
        let viewModel = CalculatorLiftEventViewModelFromLiftEvent(withLiftEvent: liftEvent, dataManager: dataManager)
        initialViewController.viewModel = viewModel
        initialViewController.dataManager = dataManager
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I determined that `CalculatorLiftEventViewModelFromLiftEvent` objects are never being deallocated which tells me I've got a strong reference cycle that won't let go:

[image]

That will have to be another SO question.